# Performance Hit? list of anonymous type to achieve something like this List<int, string, ...> (a multi-dimensional list of multiple types) in c#)

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types, generic-collections

I am wondering about whether or not creating a list of an anonymous type is the best way to effectively create a list of multiple types as well as its effect on general performance and efficiency. Mainly I just want to know if there is a more standard way of doing List?

Situation 
I every now and then find myself with a need to create a list that has multiple values each of a different type, List. Normally i would just resolve this with a Dictionary, but then there are the cases where i don't care about duplicated key values or need a 3rd (or rarely 4th) value. Usually this is for temporary list that just track something contained in a method like logging thrown errors and an associated value so that at the end of the method i can string together the messages for a log file or something.

What i have so far is this:

```
var list = new[] { new { RowNumber = 1, Message = "" } }.ToList();
list.Clear();//clears out the example used to create the anonymous type
list.Add(new { RowNumber = 10, Message = "bla bla" }); //adding to the list
```

I am debating on doing something like an extension or something to make this easier, but if the performance  sucks or there is a better way, i would like to know.

Comment: If you're going as far as creating a list and clearing it in order to use these types, then I'd say you should define a concrete type. You can make it an inner class if you don't plann to reuse it.

Comment: The whole point of this is that i don't want to create an extra concrete class just for something that is only used once, not being passed around, and (normally) is contained with in one method. As far as readability goes i think that having extra classes to just hold 3 to 4 values internally is less readable then using an anonymous class (keeping in mind the fact that normally they do not go outside the method they were created in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [experimented a little](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yJpPfu). Here's what I found:

- **Anonymous types are as good as anything else.** I can't *really* say "anything," since I didn't try everything. But I can tell you that they're as good as `Tuple<>` and concrete types. This is logical, because underneath the covers, the compiler actually builds types for anonymous types. In essence, at runtime, they *are* just concrete types.
- **Your `ToList` call is redundant.** This part's important. It's not super relevant to your immediate question, but looking at your example, you do `new [] { ... }.ToList()`. This forces a loop through the array after it's created. You'd be much better off using list initialization: `new List<dynamic> { ... };`. That's what I used in my examples.

I ran tests 10,000 times each for:

- Anonymous type with array initializer (00:00:00.0050338 total)
- Anonymous type with list initializer (00:00:00.0035599 total)
- Tuple with list initializer (00:00:00.0025857 total)
- Concrete type with list initializer (00:00:00.0041538 total)

Running them again would just mix it up. The only consistent result was that arrays were, unsurprisingly, slower than going directly to a list.

---

If you're going to make an extension method, you'll probably want to go with one of the latter two options. Anonymous types don't travel well outside of their scope, as I'm sure you know. The choice is yours between concrete types and tuples. I'd go with concrete if you're using it a lot and/or outside of the original method, and a tuple if it just needs to exist somewhere. That's really a design choice that I can't make for you.

Comment: Your assumption on ToList is incorrect though, ToList calls the Constructor of list, passing the IEnumerable. There is an optimization for ICollections which uses CopyTo which is essentially Array.Copy.

However you are right that the Listinitializer is the better approach in the first place.

Comment: For my current purposes a Tuple would work fine, but the thing that bothers me about Tuples is that once created the a properties are read only. Probably here on out i will use the 'List<dynamic>'  way and forget making an extension for now. However it seems that you do not need to declare an example of the anonymous type in the List initialization, so you can skip the 'list.Clear();' bit. The one down side to doing it the 'List<dynamic>' way as oppose to the 'new[] {...}.ToList();' way (for me because i suck at spelling), is that you lose the intellisense for the internal properties.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to make a class.  The IL just makes an anonymous class in native that gets called the same way as a normal class, so there is no performance hit associated with it.  If you ever debug anonymous types, you'll notice the name has a long name like AnonymousTypes.Program+f__1

Creating a class improves the readability of your code IMO.

```
public class RowMessage
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

You can also use Tuples, but even this is still unclear:

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Tuple<int, string> myTuple = new Tuple<int, string>(1, "hi");
        List<Tuple<int, string>> myTupList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
        myTupList.Add(myTuple);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about enriching Exceptioninformation it is worth to mention that the Exceptionclass implements a property called Data which is of type IDictionary and can be used to append additional information.

```
    try
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException{ Data ={ { "TEST", "Hello World" } } };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data["TEST"]);
        ...
        e.Data.Add("Whatever", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

If you find yourself adding the same information lots of times, consider some HelperMethods that add certain information to a giving exception. This could also take care for duplicated keys which use some sort of numeric postfix that increments like fileName_1 and so on, you get the idea.
You can also create a standartized method of outputting those Information you provided yourself.

---

If you want a more Complex approach you can just simply use List but make the consumer of this list handle each kind of type. Which is basically the idea behind the [DebuggerTypeProxy-Atrribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute.aspx)

So you can for example use some pattern like this:

```
foreach(var typeGroup in additionalInformation.GroupBy(item => item.GetType())
{
    ITypedLogHandler handler = GetHandlerFor(typeGroup.Key);
    handler.WriteLog(typeGroup);
}
```

In general the only reason I can think of this whole idea to beeing valid is some convenient debuggint/loggin approach. Anything else should really use strong typing.